# Creating new Python object when using win32COM

Tags: python, com, win32com

I'm using win32COM to send commands to a software called "Robot Structural Analysis". I am able to retrieve objects that is declared inside the application, but I cannot find a way to declare new instance of a class defined in the application's API.

For example: 
`robot = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Robot.Application")`

(What I can do is)
`l = robot.dataserver.somelist`

However, in the api guidebook, there is a class named, say, XData, and I want to create a new instance of that class. What most people usually do with Excel VBA is

```
Dim x As New XData
x.property1 = 1
x.property2 = 2
...
```

But Python doesn't require declaring variable type. How can I do this using Python?

Comment: Based on the api guide book, the class is under Dispatch/XData

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a new class instance defined in the API using win32com and Python, one can do the followings:

1. Windows Start -> run regedit (Registry Editor)-> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT : 
   Here shows all the names of COM objects, such as Robot.GeoContour
2. In the Python code, the class instance should be declared as: 
   contour = win32.DispatchEx("Robot.GeoContour")